# Can a UITableViewController static cell have dynamic detail text?

Tags: ios7, storyboard, xcode5, uitableview

I created a UITableViewController with static table view cell content. I want all the titles and rows to be static. But I want the detail section to be dynamic as seen in the example below. (The Jetwork , On)

Do I have to make the table dynamic or is there another method for this?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make IBOutlet connections of UI controls whom values you want to modify, and set your value where needed.